# Repeatable start of thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

This code contains moveable pacman, who shoots little oval after pressing space button.So boolean variable is by default false.It becomes true after pressing space button, and oval is drawn.After pressing space button, also new thread is started.This thread contains code which moves oval forward, and once it reaches certain coords it dissapears.So when I press space first time, everything works fine.Actually it works fine also after more times, but elclipse keeps throwing IllegalThreadStateException.I decided to put thread code into `while(c!=22)` block, because ball dissapears when c=21, so I thought thread will keep being runnable because while condition can't be fullfilled.So my point is make that oval moving each time I press space button.**This is not whole code.Just important part.** If you'd need whole code, just let me know about it.*Thank you!!*

Thread:

```
        thread=new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(c!=22){
            try{
            for (c=0;c<=20;c++){
                newX=newX+c;
                repaint=true;
                Thread.sleep(100);  
                }
            if(c==21){
                shoot=false;
                c=0;
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException v){System.out.println(v);}
        }
        }
    };
```

paintComponent method:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    i=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jakub\\Desktop\\pm.gif");
    pacman=i.getImage();

    g.drawImage(pacman,x,y,this);

    if(!shoot)
        newX=x+20;
        newY=y+10;

    if(shoot){
    g.drawOval(newX,newY,10,10);
    }

    if(repaint)
        repaint();

}
```

Key event which starts thread:

```
if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
    shoot=true;
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) `i=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jakub\\Desktop\\pm.gif");`  Don't try to load resources in a paint method.  Instead declare them as class attributes and simply paint them when needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IllegalThreadStateException` is probably thrown because you call `Thread.start()` multiple times for the same thread object. The key to avoid this exception is to instantiate `thread` each time before starting it (the exact implementation depends on the behavior you want to achieve).